# Add object in treeView and display only Image

Tags: c#, treeview

```
public class TypeOfElement
{
    public Guid _id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public System.Drawing.Image _image { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

And list of those elements. How can i display only _image of every element in treeView.

Comment: WPF cannot display a `System.Drawing.Image`.

Comment: My bad i was wanting to tag wfa not wpf :)

Comment: You need all images have the same size <= 256x256px and add them to an imagelist. then you can use the node.imageindex to make it display in the tree.